# ContentControlOnEnter event not triggered

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've created a Word VBA app that shows and hides document sections based on checkbox selections. 
The sections are bookmarked, and their font is set to hiddden.

The VBA code below works as intended most of the time, but if the user selects and then immediately deselects a given checkbox, without first clicking elsewhere in the document, the hidden section appears but does not disappear.

I'm not sure why the ContentControlOnEnter event is not firing the second time.

```
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnEnter(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl)

    If (ContentControl.Title = "Section2CheckBox" And ContentControl.Checked = True) Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Section2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
    End If
    If (ContentControl.Title = "Section2CheckBox" And ContentControl.Checked = False) Then
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Section2").Range.Font.Hidden = True
    End If

With ActiveDocument
    .ActiveWindow.View.ShowAll = False 'Hide all formatting marks
    .ActiveWindow.View.ShowHiddenText = False 'Do not display hidden text
    .Application.Options.PrintHiddenText = False 'Do not print hidden text
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: OnEntry doesn't fire the second time as the user hasn't left the ContentControl. Think of the event as applying to a room. It will be triggered when you step into the room but cannot be triggered again unless you leave the room and come back in. I don't think there is an OnChange event so you could try adding an OnExit event to capture the state of the control as the user leaves it.

Comment: @m4o_tim If I change Document_ContentControlOnEnter to Document_ContentControlOnExit, I get an error message "Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name"

Comment: You should add the OnExit event in the same way that you did the OnEnter, from the drop-down lists at the top of the module. That way you will get the correct syntax.

Comment: @m4o_tim I haven't figured out how to add events from the dropdown, but I googled the syntax and it turns out I was missing the "Cancel As Boolean" parameter. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: You select Document from the drop down on the left and the event you want from the drop down on the right.